# Apply aggregate function to all values

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```
   Earns1 Earns2 Earns3
0    10     10     30
1    20     20     30
2    10     20     30
```

And i want to calculate the mean of all 9 values (i.e., apply an aggregate function row and column wise at the same time). I can melt it and just do the operation on the value column but feels weird that that's the best way to do it. Any ideas? Maybe applymap?

```
Expected result: 20 (mean of [10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30])
```

Edit: I forgot to explain this, the idea is to do it multiple times, probably using groupby(by="Class_column") not just once for the whole dataframe.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Feel free to propose a better title for the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to numpy array and then use `mean`:

```
a = df.to_numpy().mean()
#older pandas versions
#a = df.values.mean()
print (a)
20.0
```

EDIT: You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function for solution per groups:

```
print (df)
   Earns1  Earns2  Earns3 Class_column
0      10      10      30            a
1      20      20      30            b
2      10      20      30            b

df  = (df.groupby(by="Class_column")
         .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().mean())
         .reset_index(name='aggregated'))
print (df)
  Class_column  aggregated
0            a   16.666667
1            b   21.666667
```

Comment: That's very clear! Thanks! Seems like yours are a very clear way. What do you think about my melt solution? To me it looks quite inefficient, but I would like to read some explanation.

Comment: @Leo - I think melt is reshape and if larger dataframes, groups it should be slowier, always the best test in real data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df.mean().mean()
```

Comment: This is correct for the mean and assuming that any value is NaN. There's a lot of non associative functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Earns1=[10,20,10]. # creation of data frame
Earns2=[10,20,20]
Earns3=[30,30,30]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Earns1':Earns1,'Earns2':Earns2,'Earns3':Earns3})


df=df.to_numpy().transpose().reshape(df.size,order='C') # converting from 2D array to 1D array
print('result: {} (mean of {})'.format(df.mean(),list(df))) # printing result
```

Do you have any question?